# Connect to Pick Database using Odbc C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, multivalue-database, pick

How to Connect to PickBasic database using Ole db driver .. I need it badly help me out

Comment: Some clarification would be helpful. Do you have the PickBasic database driver, or are you wanting to find one? Do you want ODBC or OleDB (they're different technologies)? Do you want the connection string to use with ADO.NET, or basic instructions in using ADO.NET?

Comment: More information required. PickBASIC is a programming language which ships with the DBMS. Which variety of Pick are you using: D3, UniVerse etc...? All of the well known variations offer the possibility to connect via .NET

Answer (score 2):

I recently joined this company and i see they are using UniObjects.Net dll for interacting with this Data base Check it out its from IBM not sure about the performance though

Answer (score 2):

We communicate with a Pick Basic db using a utility called Redback. I tried to find more information on Redback but I'm not having any luck. This Redback plugin sits on a the same unix server as Pick. Redback has several responders that are listening for request. Using .net, we make tcp requests to redback. The redback responders pick these requests up and process them (Pick takes over from here and I'll a little fuzzy on the details). Redback then sends the response back in xml and we parse that into a dataset.

In Pick, there was a generic subroutine created to handle these redback requests. This subroutine reads the details of the request and calls the proper subroutine based on the parameters sent in from the .net side. This program also handles the xml formatting to make sure that any data sent back from a subroutine is properly encoded and formatted.

I have a few friends on Stack that program and Pick and could probably go into more detail about how redback handles requests from .net. If you want more info, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools available from www.rainingdata.com. I can't see any freeware options.

Rainingdata is now tiger logic.  http://www.tigerlogic.com/tigerlogic/

And I've been to their worldwide conferences, but I don't recall any freeware.  Its easy to program if you can stand using a dump terminal or a terminal emulation like Accuterm.  Accuterm will allow you to program with GUI interface, but you will still have a lot of fun finding the files and programs you have to use.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify which variation of the Pick OS you are running. So here's a generic solution.

I have customers using Liberty ODBC and it works just fine with the Pick OS. My customer is running mvBase. If you have D3, it already has a .net interface built in I believe.

Integration Software
604-682-8293 or fax 604-682-8499; http://www.libertyodbc.com

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to connect to the D3 Pick database using ODBC. Connecting to Pick Basic doesn't make much sense. Here is a link to the D3 ODBC documentation.

http://www.rainingdata.com/support/documentation/odbc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Create an ODBC DSN Datasource, then use it just like any other ODBC connection